# Getting "Not Found" when trying to retrieve data for DataTable

Tags: c#, jquery, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I´m working on asp.net WebApi with Angular doing `DataTable`.

**View:**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dt-bootstrap no-footer" id="tabla_catalogos" role="grid" aria-describedby="sample_editable_1_info">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="hidden"></th>
      <th style="width: 200px;"> Codigo </th>
      <th> Nombre </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Angular control:

```
 $scope.filtro = function (selected) {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID);
        }
```

Here I get values (I recieve 5 values) but for dataTable I only need `Codigo` and `Nombre`, If I test it separately I recieve parameters without problems.

So now I use it into url parameter of datatable

**Data Table:**

```
  $('#tabla_catalogos').DataTable({
        searching: true,
        dom: 'ftpB',
        buttons: [
           'excelHtml5', 'csv', 'print'
        ],
        paging: true,
        select: {
            style: 'single'
        },
        info: false,
        ordering: true,
        "processing": true,
        ajax: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: $scope.filtro = function (selected) {
                apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/" + selected.ID);
            },
            dataSrc: '',
            beforeSend: function (request) {
                request.setRequestHeader("Version", $scope.usuario.Version);
                request.setRequestHeader("Origen", 'Web');
            }
        },
        columns: [
         { data: 'Codigo' },
         { data: 'Nombre' },
        ],
        pageLength: 10
            , language: {
                "emptyTable": "No se encontraron registros",
                "zeroRecords": "No encontraron coincidencias",
                "search": "Buscar: "
            }
    });
```

But in Chrome console, I get this error:

> > NOT FOUND 404:

http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/%22%20+%20selected.ID);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D?_=1492444754842

Comment: If you check the URL it is trying to call "http://localhost:55720/api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoRegistro/selected.ID*" where it should be some number in place of "selected.ID". Check if "selected" object is reachable in DataTable config code which you have posted..

Comment: try to create a plunker and post it here which be helpful to find the issue.